# Can I use Xamarin Forms ListView with TemplateSelector and ValueConverter inside Template?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a Xamarin ListView that show items based on different DataTemplates, which works fine!
I can use Binding as expected inside the Template definitions.
But when I try to use a ValueConverter inside the Template it never gets called (The converter is working in other places of my Application).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is the ValueConverter resource defined? At the page level, the App.Xaml level, or somewhere else?

Comment: where is the code to investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I was able to get things working!

My Problem here was that I did implement INotifyPropertyChanged in my ViewModel but not implemented it for the ViewItems itself.
So, even though my ViewItems never change once they where shown in the ListView-Template, it seems to be necessary to implement INotifyPropertyChanged at least for the properties that I want to use with a ValueConverter.

By the way, using a ValueConverter with the same ViewItems without INotifyPropertyChanged **BUT** without TemplateSelector (i.e. as a ListView-HeaderTemplate), everything works as expected (at least expected by me)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, Please mark your reply as answer after three days.If will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I test a demo about `ListView` with T`emplateSelector` and `ValueConverter` inside Template.

I have two `DataTemplates`, to valiate the value of DateOfBirth.Year, if the Year is over 1980 If the year is over 1980 ,listview will be setted `ValidTemplate` , if not, listview  will be setted `InvalidTemplate`.

```
    public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate ValidTemplate { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate InvalidTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            return ((Person)item).DateOfBirth.Year >= 1980 ? ValidTemplate : InvalidTemplate;
        }
    }
```

In the location, it will have 0 or 1 value, then I will convert it to the True or False by following code.

```
    public class MyValueConvert : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (int)value != 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is my xaml layout.

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MyValueConvert x:Key="intToBool" />

            <DataTemplate x:Key="validPersonTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Green" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateOfBirth, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" TextColor="Green" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Location, Converter={StaticResource intToBool}}" TextColor="Green" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="invalidPersonTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateOfBirth, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" TextColor="Red" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Location, Converter={StaticResource intToBool}}" TextColor="Red" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:PersonDataTemplateSelector x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector" ValidTemplate="{StaticResource validPersonTemplate}" InvalidTemplate="{StaticResource invalidPersonTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Label Text="ListView with a DataTemplateSelector" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="0,20,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personDataTemplateSelector}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is running sceenshot.

[image]

Here is my demo.

https://github.com/851265601/XFormsData-TempleSelect

Comment: hmm,.. looks like the more or less exact same thing doesn't work for me :(
I will try to post some code this evening